# Assign a result of a logic operation between Eigen/Dense arrays to a std::vector

Tags: c++, eigen

I am dealing with  library.

I can `cout<<(PointsSorted.col(0).array()<0)<<endl;`

### The output is:

1
1
1
1
1
0
0
0
0

### 0

But how can I assign this output into a std::vector. I have a slow solution to do this by a pointer.I am wondering if there is a faster way like:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back((PointsSorted.col(0).array()<0));
```

Comment: `v.push_back((PointsSorted.col(0).array()<0));` What would the contents of `v` be after that?

Comment: I just want to save the output into v. Right now, I can cout the output, but I don know how to save them into a std: vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already answered this question on another forum, but for the record you can view a `std::vector<int>` as an `Eigen::VectorXi`. Here is a self-contained example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  MatrixXd points = MatrixXd::Random(6,6);
  int n = points.rows();
  std::vector<int> v(n);
  VectorXi::Map(v.data(), n) = (points.col(2).array()<0).cast<int>();
  for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) cout << v[i];
  cout << endl;
}
```